# Adjust PDF colors on a dark document (for print)

Tags: pdf, colors

**Summary**: Have to print several PDF's coming with dark, dull colors, the printed result is very dark and often bleeding ink. I can compensate easily using the printer's color adjustment on Canon Printers (brightness, intensity, contrast, etc), that's awesome but I can't do the same on HP printers as there is no color adjustment. I'm not producing the PDF's so my options are limited, I just receive the files, educating the customers to produce quality PDF is sadly out of the question.

I would like to find a way to adjust the colors on the PDF itself and keeping it as PDF or saving it as a new one, also keeping the lines (raster) and pixels. Is there a way to do this? I would love having a virtual PDF printer with color adjustments (just like canon printers), so I could send this PDF's to print and save, getting a new color adjusted document.

Details on what I have achieved so far with limited results:

- Open in Photoshop and adjust. Perfect, I can do whatever I want but
  the whole page is converted into pixels, I don't want that. Besides
  this only works page-by-page and I'm working with 500 page documents
  so this is not a practical option.
- XNConvert works great and converts
  each page into whatever format I want also applying filters like
  brightness and contrast, etc, but it also converts everything into
  pixels. Despite experimenting diff configurations, it causes issues
  with fine lines (0.5 or hairlines are turned into 1pt lines).
- IrfanView also works great just like XNConvert but it messes up the
  text, can't recognized the embedded fonts and also converts
  everything into pixels, I don't want that.
- PrintFab (RIP software) is
  the best thing I have tried in this sense but still with limitations.
  Yes it works great and I can adjust brightness, contrast, etc while
  keeping everything as a printjob (pixels and raster) but it doesn't
  have full support for the family of HP printers I have, the end
  result is it makes the printer work in CMY mode, without blank ink.
- Old Macromedia Freehand could import some PDF documents and allowed manual color adjustments affecting both images and line objects while keeping them as they are (without turning everything into pixels), but it doesn't work with all PDFs (importing, that is), and it's a pain with multipage PDFs.
- I have worked with ImageMagick in the past but not in this way, I believe the available options would also turn lines into pixels.
- Currently exploring the Adobe Acrobat convert color options but suddenly stopped working, will keep trying.

I worked on the printing industry for years and we often received terrible PDF files for printing magazines, but the specialized RIP software allowed great freedom of modifications on color and profiles. I can't achieve the same on HP printers so far, and using ICC profiles has great limitations in regard of my problem (bad pdfs from clients).

After lots of research it seems I would have to give up my HP equipment and buy Canon, Epson or Brother so I can get access to full printing color adjustments on the fly but that's not a realistic option for me right now (BTW I'm talking about printing lots, lots of pages).

I must be missing something here, there must be another way to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are they sending RGB or CMYK? Do they look bad on-screen, or just at print? Is your own workflow properly managed?

Comment: What systems are you on? What is your printer model? In Linux, instead of dealing with the PDF directly, you would change that (say gamma) in the CUPS driver. HP printers are pretty well supported via HPLIP.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. They are sending RGB Pdfs, mostly created on Word or Adobe Indesign. Some do look bad on screen and print due to very bad color selections and terrible pictures taken by them. I have worked using diff workflows in diff jobs (companies) but here the issue is people creating the wrong documents and I have no control over it. It's like a copy center... people bring what they bring. Some bring documents with text using light gray (too light) and others bring too dark pictures or bad 3d renders.

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo Trápani, right now I'm using HP7740 among others, but that one is the most robust for the amount of prints. I was using Brother and Canon printers with great success as I can adjust the colors with the driver, but... the equivalent printers (for high volume printing) are too expensive (HP too, but  happen to have some already). Interesting, yes I've been considering testing Linux, what you say helps me to move this option to the top of the list. Gamma adjustment would be a great help, limited but great.

Comment: ahh… so really you need some kind of 'normalisation' technique… squeeze appalling consumer originals into some kind of acceptable gamut range. Sorry, I wish I could help - I could perhaps do that for rasters in Ps [one at a time], but idk how to even approach it for vectors. Wish you luck :)

Comment: Yes!. (sorry forgot to post these details: I'm on Windows, I can try on Linux in fact I will based on the comment about gamma on CUPS, sounds like a good option to try.

Converting everything to pixels on Photoshop could be an option but the processing power increases, specially dealing with 11x17" pages, 100, 200, etc. The whole page becomes an image, that's way heavy compared to raster + pixels on a document. Again, educating a client or clients is too difficult, specially dealing with diff clients over and over.

Thanks everyone, will explore the CUPS options on Linux.

Comment: Sadly, Linux CUPS didn't work. Installed everything and I can see the settings for gamma, hue, saturation, etc. But any change I make there doesn't have any effect on the printed result. These printers don't seem to allow any modifications on the color as Canon, Brother or Epson does. I'm talking about the HP OfficeJet Pro series, great printers but limited in this regard for my work.